# access variables through request body in node js express

Tags: jquery, node.js

I am new to node js. I want to access the value of a variable that is in a HTML page through node js express.

My HTML side code written within the script tags is

```
 $.ajax({
                        url: '/modulename',
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'JSON',
                        data: JSON.stringify([
                        {module:"abc"}]),

                        success: onMemberSucces,
                        error: onMemberError
                    });
```

The packages I am using for my js application are

```
"dependencies": {
"all": "0.0.0",
"body-parser": "^1.15.1",
"cookie-parser": "^1.4.2",
"d3": "^3.5.17",
"express": "^4.13.4",
"jquery": "^2.2.4",
"jsdom": "^9.2.1",
"mssql": "^3.3.0",
"node-sqlserver-unofficial": "1.4.0",
"require": "^2.4.20",
"requirejs": "^2.2.0"
}
```

The code on my js application is

```
app.use(express.static('D:/d3 project/project_part1/project_part1/'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
var server = app.listen(8081);

app.post('/modulename', function (req, res, body) {
modulename = req.body;
console.log("hi \n"+ modulename);
console.log("hi "+ modulename.module);

});
```

the output on the console is

```
hi [object Object]
hi undefined
```

I have tried to print

```
 modulename.data
```

This also prints undefined at the console. I am doing a very careless silly mistake,but I am not able to figure it out and have spent quite a few hours on it. Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're sending an array... `modulename[0].module`.

Comment: `function (req, res)` and not `function (req, res, body)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the data to

```
data: {module:"abc"},
```

Jquery will take care of the rest,
in your node route

`console.log(req.body.module)`

Answer (score 0):

The array is not needed here, you can change:

```
JSON.stringify([
    {
        module: "abc"
    }
]),
```

To:

```
JSON.stringify({
    module: "abc"
}),
```